# Spring Boot: get command line argument within @Bean annotated method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, command-line-arguments

I'm building a Spring Boot application  and need to read command line argument within method annotated with @Bean. See sample code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeService getSomeService() throws IOException {
        return new SomeService(commandLineArgument);
    }
}
```

How can I solve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
@Bean
public SomeService getSomeService(@Value("${property.key}") String key) throws IOException {
    return new SomeService(key);
}
```

Comment: I've never used that annotation and probably I'm wrong but, shouldn't be `@Value("#{systemProperties.propertyName}") String key` ?

Comment: thanks, it works. Correct placeholder is ${property.key}

Answer (score 15):

```
 @Bean
 public SomeService getSomeService(
   @Value("${cmdLineArgument}") String argumentValue) {
     return new SomeService(argumentValue);
 }
```

To execute use `java -jar myCode.jar --cmdLineArgument=helloWorldValue`

Answer (score 6):

You can also inject [`ApplicationArguments`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationArguments.html) directly to your bean definition method and access command line arguments from it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeService getSomeService(ApplicationArguments arguments) throws IOException {
        String commandLineArgument = arguments.getSourceArgs()[0]; //access the arguments, perform the validation
        return new SomeService(commandLineArgument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run your app like this:

```
$ java -jar -Dmyproperty=blabla myapp.jar
```

or

```
$ gradle bootRun -Dmyproperty=blabla
```

Then you can access this way:

```
@Bean
public SomeService getSomeService() throws IOException {
    return new SomeService(System.getProperty("myproperty"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run your app like this:

$ java -server -Dmyproperty=blabla -jar myapp.jar

and can access the value of this system property in the code.

Comment: Read the value of the property using 
@Value("myproperty")
String key;

 in java code.