# Call Spring PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with Custom Parameter like File

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I try to run my spring boot project, I get an error like that:

Description:

> Parameter 0 of method propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in
>   AppConfig required a bean of type 'java.io.File' that
>   could not be found.

Action:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'java.io.File' in your configuration.

@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class AppRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(AppRunner.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("path\\credentials.properties");
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer report =
                beanFactory.getBean(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.class, file);
    }
}
```

My configuration file looks like that:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(File file) throws IOException {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(Utils.getProperties(file));
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

I want to call singleton bean with parameter. But I try to it like that I get an error like defined above. How can I solve this?

Comment: Don't... Instead either use Spring Boot to automatically load that file by specifying `spring.additional.confg-location` or by adding an `@PropertySource` annotation. Don't redefine the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, File path comes from console args. It is not constant value.

Comment: Then use `spring.additional.config-locations`.. Specify that as an argument when running the application. You are making things too complex (and your setup won't work either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved according to comment of @M. Deinum like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class AppRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.additional-location","path\\credentials.properties");
        SpringApplication.run(AppRunner.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or using Environment:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig  implements EnvironmentAware {

    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Properties properties = Utils.getProperties(new File(env.getProperty("credential")));
        properties.setProperty("startDate",env.getProperty("startDate"));
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(properties);
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        env = environment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your intention for using the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer? You did already created the Bean, so you are able to inject it via @Autowired.

The method with the @Bean annotation is called via Spring on application startup. If you want to initialize that bean manually, you have to remove the @Bean annotation or create a file based bean in your AppConfig class:

```
@Bean
public File getFile() {
    return new File("path\\credentials.properties");
}
```

EDIT:

Take a look at this post, if you want to use command line values while creating beans with the @Bean annotation: [Spring Boot: get command line argument within @Bean annotated method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269831/spring-boot-get-command-line-argument-within-bean-annotated-method)

Comment: thanks for your response. The problem is "path\\credentials.properties" is not constant, it is a custom value and it is taken from console. Later, I want to use it in PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269831/spring-boot-get-command-line-argument-within-bean-annotated-method

Here you can see how you can use command line arguments while creating beans with @Bean. Otherwise you can access the spring boot properties via injection the Environment.